# discrete mathematics exercise

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Andrea has $46$ rectangular pieces of paper. If $l, w$ (measured in centimeters) denote the
length and width, respectively, of each rectangular piece, we find that each of $l, w$ is a
positive integer, where $1 \le w \le l \le 90.$

We want to prove that Andrea can always select
two rectangular pieces, say $R_1$ and $R_2$, from these $46$ rectangular pieces, so that $R_2$
completely covers $R_1$ when $R_2$ is placed on top of $R_1$. We shall prove this by considering
each of the following cases:

$(a)$ There are two or more square pieces among these $46$ rectangular pieces.

$(b)$ None of these $46$ rectangular pieces are square.

$(c)$ There is exactly one square piece among these $46$ rectangular pieces.

I need some hints or examples on what kind of concepts are we supposed to use here. I am not sure how to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINTS** (a) is trivial, since of the two square pieces, the larger covers the smaller.

Now if any two pieces share the same length or width, (or the length of one equals the width of the other) then the piece with the larger "other" dimension covers the smaller piece.  So if we have no covers, then there are 46 pairs of numbers, with no two numbers being equal:  How can that happen if all the numbers are 90 or less?

Case (c) is very similar: excluding the length of the one square piece, there are 89 numbers to use for 45 pieces.